# What makes the OrderBy custom pipe fail in in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular14

I have been developing an e-commerce app with Angular 14 and Angular Material.

I am currently working on a form, among others, contains a  elements populated with all the countries of the World that I get from **[restcountries.com](https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v3-all)**.

In the `countries.service.ts` file I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CountriesService {

  apiURL: string = 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1';

  constructor (private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCountries(): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiURL}/all`);
  }
}
```

I use the service in the form component:

```
import { CountriesService } from '../../services/countries.service';

export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

  public countries!: any;
  
  constructor (private countriesService: CountriesService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCountries();
  }
  
  public getCountries() {
    this.countriesService.getCountries().subscribe(response => {
      this.countries = response;
    });
  }
  
}


<mat-form-field appearance="outline" floatLabel="always">
    <mat-label>Country:</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="country" [(value)]="this.selectedCountry">
        <mat-option value="">Select a country</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries | OrderBy: 'country.name.common'" [value]="country.cca2">
            {{country.name.common}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

#### The goal

I use this `OrderBy` custom pipe to **order the countries by name** (from A to Z), in the drop-down:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'OrderBy'})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(input: any, key: string) {
    if (!input) return [];

    return input.sort(function(itemA: any, itemB: any) {
      if (itemA[key] > itemB[key]) {
        return 1;
      } else if (itemA[key] < itemB[key]) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }

}
```

#### The problem

For a reason I have bean unable to understand, the ordering fails, the countries list stays unchanged.

#### EDIT

Alternatives like this also do not work:

```
public getCountries() {
    this.countriesService.getCountries().subscribe(response => {
      this.countries = response;
      this.countries.sort(function(a: any, b: any) {
        return a.name.common - b.name.common;
      });
    });
}
```

##### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the easiest and most reliable way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, the `input` in the pipe is the `countries` array and the key is `country.name.common`. If so, then what is the result of `itemA[key]`? I think, it is a `country` object and not the `country.name.common` value itself. Maybe it should be something like that: `itemA.name.common` and `itemB.name.common`, becaus `itemA` and `itemB` should be a country object. This is only guessing. If it is not the case, then why not simply order the countries in the ts code?

Comment: Your pipe is impure. By definition this is a bad idea, and an Angular anti-pattern: you should use something other than a pipe here. If you want to brute force a solution, try adding `pure: false` to the configuration object passed to the `@Pipe` decorator. I'm not 100% sure it will work, and again, you shouldn't be ordering an array this way.

Comment: I don't think you can even use a pipe in an `*ngFor`, for that matter.

Comment: @derstauner I need a general use pipe, it seems. And I would prefer a general use one. But I don't know how to obtain it.

Comment: Ok, but you could write a general function in a service and use that in any ts file. And did you try the suggestions from me?

Comment: `| OrderBy: 'country.name.common` this line use this `| OrderBy: 'name.common` without country. But @Will Alexander say the right: It's anti -pattern.

Comment: @Flo I did, but it does not change anything. I can agree it's an antipattern. What is a batter alternative? :)

Comment: Why don't you sort the array in the class? Or even when you get it back from the server? If need be, you can always clone the array and sort the clone if you don't want to modify the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key in the pipe has the value `'country.name.common'`

I doubt your country actually has a field 'country.name.common' but rather consists of multiple nested objects.

Thus `itemA[key]` returns `undefined`, same for `itemB[key]`, so your ordering function returns 0 for every element. The list remains unchanged.

Comment: What would be a viable alternative (for a general use sorting pipe)?

Comment: My team uses this (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-get-method/) library function. But I have to admit I am clueless if this is good practice or not.